# Is it possible to create Azure Maps SAS token programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

This question for Azure maps Not for Storage account.

we implemented SAS token key for Azure maps instead for subscription key. Is it possible to create azure maps SAS token programmatically?, so it can be periodically renew the token whenever it get expire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's how Azure Active Directory Tokens work. All the docs follow a similar pattern:

1. Request a token from a trusted endpoint. I often use a simple Azure function or add a simple REST service as part of an Azure Web app.
2. Pass token down to client application.
3. When token expires, request a new one.

Here are some useful resources:

- Azure Maps Auth docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-authentication
- Official Azure Maps Auth samples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Maps-AzureAD-Samples
- A sample Azure Function that I used for doing this: https://github.com/microsoft/satellite-imagery-labeling-tool/blob/main/maps-auth/GetAzureMapsToken.cs

If using the Azure Maps Web SDK, it will automatically request a new token when it expires. The token is a JWT token. If you are calling REST services directly with them and not using the Web SDK, you can parse the JWT token to get the expiry time. When it expires, request a new token.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. can you pls. provide some code samples according to the screenshot . above links code samples are not having expiry date, also there is no Signing key value input.

Comment: You would use a JWT library to do the parsing. There are lots available for each programming language.

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt, Thanks for your time and answers.
I have raised the same question with microsoft support team. i got a answer, that as of now there is no option for generate the azure maps SAS token programmatically. they'll include this feature in upcoming release.

FYR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1305191/is-it-possible-to-create-azure-maps-sas-token-prog?source=docs

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding on the type of token that is generated. You can definately generate JWT tokens from the service today for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For people who come across this question and are looking for an implementation in Python to generate SAS tokens programmatically, here is a solution using the [azure-mgmt-maps](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-maps/) package from the Microsoft Azure SDK for Python:

```py
import datetime

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.maps import AzureMapsManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.maps.models import AccountSasParameters, SigningKey


def format_time(time: datetime.datetime) -> str:
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'


client = AzureMapsManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(), 
    subscription_id="[your_subscription_id]"
)
time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
sas_params = AccountSasParameters(
    signing_key=SigningKey.MANAGED_IDENTITY,
    principal_id="[your_managed_id_principal_id]",
    max_rate_per_second=500,
    start=format_time(time_now),
    expiry=format_time(time_now + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)),
    regions=["westeurope"]
)
sas_token = client.accounts.list_sas(
    resource_group_name="[your_resource_group_name]",
    account_name="[your_azure_maps_account_name]",
    maps_account_sas_parameters=sas_params
)
print(sas_token.account_sas_token)
```